# How do i remove all the tbody elements in the "rtable" table except for the first 2

Tags: jquery

I need to remove most of the tbody's in this code with jquery but not sure how i have googled and have found no simple way to do so. I'm no expect at coding but i try.

```
<body>


<div id="page" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <table id="page" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" widht="100%" height="100%">
  <tbody><tr><td valign="top" class="menu">

  </td><td valign="top" id="right">
    <table id="rtable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody><tr><td valign="top">
      <div id="content"><table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td colspan="20" class="sep"><h2><span>General</span></h2></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="value" colspan="20" style="min-width: 205px;"></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Name</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><input type="text"></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Default Zoom</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span class="select"><select size="1"><option value="10">10%</option><option value="100">100%</option><option value="200">200%</option><option value="25">25%</option><option value="33">33%</option><option value="400">400%</option><option value="50">50%</option><option value="75">75%</option><option value="4294967295">Fit</option></select></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Status</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span class="rovalue">down</span></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td colspan="20" class="sep"><h2><span>Polling</span></h2></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Enabled</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Probe Interval</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Probe Timeout</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Probe Down Count</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Use Notifications</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Notifications</span></td><td class="value" colspan="19"><div><div><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></div></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td colspan="20" class="sep"><h2><span>Appearance</span></h2></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Label Refresh Interval</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span class="cbox"><select size="1"><option value="0">default</option></select><input type="text" style="width: 122px; height: 19px;"></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Background</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="up.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Image</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span class="select"><select size="1"><option value="26753564">CCTV.jpg</option><option value="60131">access_point.png</option><option value="38329152">ap.svg</option><option value="38328881">ap.svg</option><option value="38329151">bridge.svg</option><option value="38328882">bridge.svg</option><option value="38329150">client.svg</option><option value="38328883">client.svg</option><option value="38329149">clock.svg</option><option value="38328884">clock.svg</option><option value="38329148">dns.svg</option><option value="38328885">dns.svg</option><option value="38329147">file_server.svg</option><option value="38328886">file_server.svg</option><option value="38329146">globe.svg</option><option value="38328887">globe.svg</option><option value="38329145">globe2.svg</option><option value="38328888">globe2.svg</option><option value="38329144">grid.png</option><option value="38328889">grid.png</option><option value="38329143">imac.svg</option><option value="38328890">imac.svg</option><option value="38329142">laptop.svg</option><option value="38328891">laptop.svg</option><option value="38329141">mail.svg</option><option value="38328892">mail.svg</option><option value="38329140">news.svg</option><option value="38328893">news.svg</option><option value="38329139">news_server.svg</option><option value="38328894">news_server.svg</option><option value="4294967295">none</option><option value="38329138">ntp.svg</option><option value="38328895">ntp.svg</option><option value="38329137">pc.svg</option><option value="38328896">pc.svg</option><option value="38329136">pc2.svg</option><option value="38328897">pc2.svg</option><option value="38329135">pc3.svg</option><option value="38328898">pc3.svg</option><option value="38329134">pop.svg</option><option value="38328899">pop.svg</option><option value="38329133">printer.svg</option><option value="38328900">printer.svg</option><option value="38329132">rack.svg</option><option value="38328901">rack.svg</option><option value="38329131">rb.svg</option><option value="38328902">rb.svg</option><option value="38329130">router.svg</option><option value="38328903">router.svg</option><option value="38329129">smtp.svg</option><option value="38328904">smtp.svg</option><option value="38329128">sql.svg</option><option value="38328905">sql.svg</option><option value="38329127">switch.svg</option><option value="38328906">switch.svg</option></select></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Scale</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><input type="text">%</td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Tile</span></td><td class="extra"></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Device</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Unknown Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Up Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Down Partial Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Down Complete Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Acked Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Label</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Shape</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="select" style="visibility: hidden;"><select size="1" disabled=""><option value="3">cloud</option><option value="1">diamond</option><option value="4">hexagon</option><option value="5">hexagon2</option><option value="2">oval</option><option value="0">rectangle</option><option value="6">triangle</option><option value="7">triangle2</option></select></span></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Network</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Label</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Shape</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="select" style="visibility: hidden;"><select size="1" disabled=""><option value="3">cloud</option><option value="1">diamond</option><option value="4">hexagon</option><option value="5">hexagon2</option><option value="2">oval</option><option value="0">rectangle</option><option value="6">triangle</option><option value="7">triangle2</option></select></span></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Submap</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>All Unknown Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>All Up Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Some Partially Down Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Some Completely Down Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Some Acknowledged Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Label</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Shape</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="select" style="visibility: hidden;"><select size="1" disabled=""><option value="3">cloud</option><option value="1">diamond</option><option value="4">hexagon</option><option value="5">hexagon2</option><option value="2">oval</option><option value="0">rectangle</option><option value="6">triangle</option><option value="7">triangle2</option></select></span></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Static</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Shape</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="select" style="visibility: hidden;"><select size="1" disabled=""><option value="3">cloud</option><option value="1">diamond</option><option value="4">hexagon</option><option value="5">hexagon2</option><option value="2">oval</option><option value="0">rectangle</option><option value="6">triangle</option><option value="7">triangle2</option></select></span></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Link</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><span></span></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Link Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Link Full Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Link Label Color</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;">hex</div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Label</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody><tbody class=" group hidden"><tr><td class="label" style="min-width: 205px;"><span>Thickness</span></td><td class="extra"><a class="sbtn" draggable="false"><img src="down.png"></a></td><td class="value" colspan="18"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><input type="text" disabled="" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
    </td></tr></tbody></table>
 </td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="iframe.html" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: try with `$('#rtable tbody tr').remove()` this will remove every tr and it's content. If you want to keep something we need to know what you want saved.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase that. I need to remove all tboby's from the table that is under div id="contect". the table that starts with <table class="list" but i want to keep the first 2 tbody's in that table

Comment: Then you need `$('#rtable #contect tbody').remove()`

Comment: This is what i want the `div id="content"` section to look like. `<div id="content"><table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td colspan="20" class="sep"><h2><span>General</span></h2></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td class="value" colspan="20" style="min-width: 205px;"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>`

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems this is what i needed to add

```
    document.querySelector("#content tbody").remove();
    $("#content").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
```